# Increase quota limit for YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to increase the quota limit for YouTube Data API v3.

When I go to this form - https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest

I can't submit it, because 'reCaptcha v1 is shutdown'

Google Team, fix this problem, please.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hack. Create multiple API keys in the Google developer console:

And loop through the list of these API keys. Again this is not a permanent solution, but if your request is limited this might be useful.